# Has Facebook considered a system of micro payments to pay users for the work they do in improving their Facebook?

Tags: macroeconomics

Facebook, notoriously, crowd-sources through the internet to improve their product - Facebook. This without any payment.

Given the vast computing power that is now available and the kind of personal data that they farm it seems plausible that one can set up a system of micro-payments to pay back users for the work that they do to improve Facebook.

**Q. Has any of the tech giants - and specifically Facebook - looked into this?**

**Q. Has there been any academic studies of such a system?**

Note: This question should be tagged as digital-economics - but there is no such tag.

Comment: As people are doing the work for free, why should they pay them?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Wait until they realise they've been suckered. Then governments will have a real revolution on their hands and not just a fake one. The Big Tech companies will then have to come up with some damn good answers or they will be in real trouble - and not just fake trouble.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Remember it took the Bourgeois revolution to move us on from feudalism where people, aka the peasants, were doing work for 'free'. And look at how much trouble that caused in the last three centuries since the French Revolution.

Comment: You might want to check out the extant work on intrinsic vs extrinsic motivation: the implications for your question are relevant. Whereas your colourful analogies do not seem to be relevant to the question.